# no bootloader appears to be present at all. thanks grub

Tags: grub2, partitioning, bootloader, canonical

so i am on a compaq presario cq57. i installed ubuntu 14.04.3 and after fighting with it a couple days it finally installed. First it wouldn't, said something about grub 2 and a fatal error, so i repartitioned everything again, thinking i had nailed it for sure this time. mistake. now there is no bootloader present at all and i have to have the live cd to boot. i wiped windows out while installing ubuntu. i have read a few answers on similar questions but none of those solutions work for me. i just want to install grub 2 and be done with it. it says it can't find canonical path for /cow. it's extremely frustrating, anyone that can help would be a lifesaver.

Comment: So you want to scrap Windows and just have Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes!  I hate Windows, and Windows 7 is almost not supported at all anymore. So yes, i just want to get rid of Windows (which i already accomplished) and stick  with ubuntu. Grub is there, i found it in my files. I guess it's just not signed to a partition ? I'm not sure

Comment: OK, simplest thing to do:  Put in the install DVD and select Install Ubuntu.  When asked, select to remove everything and install Ubuntu.  That should work.

Comment: i tried that last night, it still flashes the grub failed something or other fatal error message. is there a way to access the partition table without running through the whole process again? like from terminal or something?

Comment: Yeah, open a Terminal, type `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and press `p`, then hit enter.  Be very careful in this tool.

Comment: Awesome , I'll try that as soon as i get off work today!  I'll let you know how it pans out!

Comment: That will just print the partition table.  If you really want to start from scratch, boot from a Live USB and type `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` and wait a couple hours for that to complete.  Then restart the whole installation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal window and run

```
grub-install /dev/sda1 --force
```

It should work fine now.